# @reply 名を自動補完したら、名前の後にコロン+スペースを入れる

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, コメント

補完候補が出ている時に

[image: completing]

タブキーを押して補完し

[image: completed]

そのまま続けて入力すると

[image: no ping]

ユーザー名の後にスペースなどの有効な区切り文字がないため通知が飛びません。

英語であれば、自然とユーザー名の後に区切りとしてスペースを入れますが、日本語の場合、ユーザー名に続く文字の文字種が違えば (アルファベットでなければ) @reply を判定してくれるだろうと思ってスペースを入れない可能性があります。

ツイッターを使う人なら後にスペースを入れるのに慣れているかもしれませんが、意図しない間違いをシステム的に防止できた方がよいと思います。

```
@reply: それはそうですね。
```

単にスペースだけでなく、コロン+スペースがよい理由は、スペースだけだとスペースを削除して「さん」付けしたくなりそうだからです。

Comment: ナイスキャッチ！これはちょっと難しい問題みたいです。とりあえず開発者へ投げましたが、解決まで時間がかかる可能性が高いです。ご了承ください。

Comment: @jmac 了解です。[通知先を表示するようにした方が](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment)簡単かもしれませんね

Answer (score 2):

`@name`も利用しているツイッターもスペースや区切り文字が必要ため、これは現在治す必要はないと開発者が判断しました。

Comment: Twitterでは`@name`を補完すると半角スペースが挿入されますが、SOではその予定もないのでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist 開発者に上記のアイデアを連絡しました。これで是非するとは言えないですが、いい提案でした。ありがとう！

Comment: @unarist 適用しました。スペースが自動的に追加させます。